# Making two separate teapots in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glm-math

I want to make two separate teapots, but two teapots overlap.

How do I fix the code to separate the two teapots?

```cpp
void display() {

    glClearColor(0,0,1,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    mat4 mv; 
    const vec3 center(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    if (useGlu) mv = glm::lookAt(eye,center,up); 
    else {
        mv = Transform::lookAt(eye,up); 
    }
    glLoadMatrixf(&mv[0][0]); 

    glutSolidTeapot(2);
    glutSolidTeapot(2.5);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: In addition to answer I see no `glFlush()` or `glFinish()` before `glutSwapBuffers()` ...

Comment: @Spektre Flush/Finish not required with double buffered contexts

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your modelling coordinates origin before generating the second teapot:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(-6.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glutSolidTeapot(2.5);
```

Comment: i do what you say , do not see a teapot(2.5)

Comment: Oh I just noticed you're already using GL_MODELVIEW above.  You should use GL_PROJECTION for viewing, and GL_MODELVIEW for modelling.

Comment: @PaulBentley: You definitely shouldn't used the projection matrix for viewing. That would invalidate the whole lighting pipeline since this has to happen in view-space in the fixed function pipeline.

Comment: -6 probably too much,

Comment: @MrD isn't the projection matrix used to set the view volume?

Comment: @PaulBentley actually, there's no difference. You can put any transform in any matrix. This separation is just for convenience. Normally, projection matrix used only for projection transformation, and modelview for model and view - and this is sort of OpenGL design mistake I think. In DX ffp you have three separate matrices for model (called world), view and projection. They just applied altogether for vertex and you can use one composite matrix for doing any transform. OpenGL solved this by adding matrix stack and reversing oder of transformations - now all of this is obsolete.